# execCommand on elements inside iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I have a wysiwyg page editor where users can add ready-made blocks and other content to a page (inside Iframe) and drag them around. At the moment they can click an 'edit text' button to change contents of elements (`h`-tags, `p`-tags, `a`-tags), but we would like to have this functionality using the `contenteditable` attribute.

The page inside the Iframe (template) is loaded from the same domain.
The `contenteditable` attribute is set to `true` on mouseover and `false` on mouseleave (unless user focussed it, then blur will disable `contenteditable`). (This works)

And now I would like to add buttons which trigger `execCommand()`. My eventlistener is triggering on click, the selection will still be there in the editable element, but nothing changed at all.

```
$('.page-builder-viewport').on('load', function() {
    var viewport = $(this).contents(), // The Iframe
    doc = $('#viewport_en').get(0).contentWindow || $('#viewport_en').get(0).contentDocument;
    // $('#viewport_en').get(0) was $(this)[0] first, but did not make difference.
    if(doc.document) {
        doc = doc.document;
    }

    ..[Deleted wall of code]..

    // This is how I try to trigger `execCommand()`
    viewport.on("click", ".btn-text-underline", function (e) {

        console.log(doc); // To be sure target is correct
        doc.execCommand('underline',false,null);
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

The `console.log()` prints the Iframe document.
Am I missing something?

Could it be because I have multiple Iframes on the page?

Comment: Is it loaded over the same subdomain as well?

Comment: Yes it is loaded from same domain and subdomain.